# Vue DOM element scrollTop is inaccessible

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get/set the `scrollTop` property of a `div` in Vue. It seems to be a very simple business...

```
<div class="list-wrapper" ref="siteList" @scroll="onScroll($event)">
```

and then in my method (I'm using class style syntax):

```
onClickThing() {
  console.log(this.$refs.siteList.scrollTop);
}
```

This seems to be correct, but it causes a build error:

```
117:37 Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Element | Element[] | Vue | Vue[]'.
Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Element[]'.
```

[image]

But this implementation works:

```
onClickThing() {
  console.log(this.$refs.siteList['scrollTop']);
}
```

So... why? If I output `this.$refs` to the console, `siteList` exists in it, and it has the `scrollTop` property. Why is it inaccessible then?

Comment: Where exactly do you see that error? Could you provide some context around it? Also, are you using Typescript?

Comment: It's a build error on the console.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot? You can paste images directly from your clipboard into the question editor

Comment: Sure: https://ibb.co/58RZznh

Comment: RIght, so it's a Typescript error. My Typescript is rusty as always but try `(this.$refs.siteList as Element).scrollTop`

Comment: Yes, it's TypeScript, I forgot to mention that. Oh dammit now I remember running into this one once. Thanks, it works!